# Make multiple ggplot have the same point colours in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendrogram, aesthetics

I need to show 3 ggplot scatterplots and one dendrogram on one page. How can I make the point colours the same in each scatter plot (i.e. I need the points for group two to be the same colour for all 3 graphs).

```
require(graphics)
require(ggplot)
require(ggdendro)


#Scatter plots
df1<-data.frame(x=c(3,4,5),y=c(15,20,25),grp=c(1,2,2))
df1$grp =factor(df1$grp)
colnames(df1)[3]="Group"
p<-ggplot(df1,aes(x,y))
p<-p+ geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Group)),size=4)
p1<-p + coord_fixed()


df2<-data.frame(x=c(3,4,5,6),y=c(15,20,25,30),grp=c(1,2,2,3))
df2$grp =factor(df2$grp)
colnames(df2)[3]="Group"
p<-ggplot(df2,aes(x,y))
p<-p+ geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Group)),size=4)
p2<-p + coord_fixed()


df3<-data.frame(x=c(3,4,5,6,7),y=c(15,20,25,30,35),grp=c(1,2,2,3,4))
df3$grp =factor(df3$grp)
colnames(df3)[3]="Group"
p<-ggplot(df3,aes(x,y))
p<-p+ geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Group)),size=4)
p3<-p + coord_fixed()

#Dendrogram
dis <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")       
d<-as.dendrogram(dis)
ddata<-dendro_data(d,type="rectangle")
dp<-ggplot(segment(ddata)) + geom_segment(aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend))
dp<-dp+geom_hline(aes(yintercept=50),colour="red")
```

I tried used the [multi plot function](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Multiple%20graphs%20on%20one%20page%20%28ggplot2%29/)
   multiplot(p1,p2,p3,dp,cols=2)
and got:

[image]

Bonus: The graphs all have a fixed aspect ratio such that scatterplot are different sizes, which is fine but I really don't need the scatterplot to take up so much space. How can I control how much space each figure is given in the final figure?

Comment: ?scale_colour_manual ...

Comment: Yep that worked. Do you know if there is a better way of combining the plots than using the 'multi plot function' so that I can control the size of the 'windows?

Comment: try `library(gridExtra); ?grid.arrange`

Comment: if you get a good solution, come back and post an answer to your own question ...